# Called method is not working C++

Tags: c++, class, object, codeblocks

I have a class called `woodyard`. Inside there is a method called `collect_wood`. It's parameter is a `Player` object. The method adds 1 to `player.wood_resource` each time it is called.

I use it in main like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < woodyards.size(); i++)
{
  woodyards[i].collect_wood(p1);
}
```

p1 is a player object.

This is the collect_wood method:

```
void woodyard::collect_wood(Player player)
{
  player.wood_resource++;
}
```

There is no effect on `wood_resource` when I run it.
Please help. I'm coding in C++ using CodeBlocks

Comment: Change your prototype to `void woodyard::collect_wood(Player &player)`. You are creating a new player each time instead of modifying the old one !

Answer (score 8):

You should use reference here.

```
void woodyard::collect_wood(Player& player)
{
  player.wood_resource++;
}
```

since in your case - you increment `wood_resource` of copy.

Comment: @ForEver is there a diff between `Player& player` and `Player &player` ?

Comment: @Antarus - nope, they're both the same (as is `Player&player`).

Answer (score 0):

Do it as Call By Reference. What your code does, it creates new `Player` each time instead of modifying old one.

```
void woodyard::collect_wood(Player& player)
{
  player.wood_resource++;
}
```

Note **`&`** in `void woodyard::collect_wood(Player& player)`

You can read more about Function call by reference [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_function_call_by_reference.htm)

Answer (score 0):

By default the functions are call by value (exceptions are there). If you need to change the original copy and not the temporary object you need to use **references** or **pointers**.

You any of the two functions:

```
void woodyard::collect_wood(Player& player)
{
  player.wood_resource++;
}
```

OR

```
void woodyard::collect_wood(Player *player)
{
  if(player)
  {
     *player.wood_resource++;
  }
}
```